# PageControl Issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a gridview when i click on any image i send current index of that gridview so i can see that image. and I am loading images from doucment. 
below is my viewDidload code.
but what my problem is. when i click any gridview item . let say its index is 4. and i set it here in currentpage=4. so when i open this page. it shows me 4th image. but my page controller current page is 4 but i can see my image which was at index 1.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
    UIImageView *subview;
    //NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor orangeColor],[UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < (NSInteger)totalImagesInGrid; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        //subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        NSString *name = [tableDataArray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i];
        NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:name];
        UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
        subview.image = loadedImage;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
        [subview release];
    }
    //float count = [totalImagesInGrid floatValue];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 13, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.pageControl.currentPage = (NSInteger)currentImage;
    NSLog(@"currentPage  %d",(NSInteger)currentImage);
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = (NSInteger)totalImagesInGrid;
    NSLog(@"(NSInteger)totalImagesInGrid  %d",(NSInteger)totalImagesInGrid);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = (NSInteger)currentImage + page;
        NSLog(@"Page %d",page);
    }
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
}

- (IBAction)changePage {
// Update the scroll view to the appropriate page
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];


pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
```

}

this is my gridview and i m click on (1,1) image.

[image]

And this is my page control view. but thats not the image i have selected . this is (0,1) image but see at page control it is on index 2.

[image]

Comment: post the method - (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)colIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set page index with selectedIndex of gridview for example see bellow...

```
- (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)colIndex{
    ///set Image with index of colIndex..
    int selectedIndex = (rowIndex*4)+colIndex;
    NSLog(@"\n Selected Image Index is %d",selectedIndex);
}
```

and in SecondView Class's `viewDidLoad:` just call your secondView class method `changePage`  at last of the method like bellow

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ////another your code
    [self changePage] 
}
```

i hope this help you..

Comment: - (void) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid didSelectRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)colIndex
{
 NSLog(@"%d, %d clicked", (rowIndex*4)+colIndex, colIndex);
}

Comment: yes thats right then whats the problem??u have an array of Images??

Comment: I am sending this  (rowIndex*4)+colIndex for currentImage to next ViewController.  and this exactly what position i want

Comment: Every time you see 1st image from this array??

Comment: 'UIImageView *subview; subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  //subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
        NSString *name = [tableDataArray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)currentImage];
        NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:name];
        UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
        subview.image = loadedImage; '

Comment: you pass the SelectedIndex with currentImage in your second class and here you not see the selected  index and see the first image everytime when you come from first class.. bcoz this you scroll the scrollview with your Selected index.. wait i will post u the code mate if it'll work i hope..

Comment: hey in viewDidLoad just call this method.. [self changePage]; or set scrollToVisibleRect with your Index*320... i hope u understand what i say..

Comment: where should i set scrollToVisibleREct

Comment: in viewDidLoad just under this two line means at last of the method just set the page mate.. under this lines    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = (NSInteger)totalImagesInGrid;
    NSLog(@"(NSInteger)totalImagesInGrid  %d",(NSInteger)totalImagesInGrid);

Comment: awesome dude.. calling [self changePage] worked for me.. Thank you so much. you are a life saver man.. Thanks again